# How to set up an ubuntu touch emulator instance behind a proxy with authentication

Tags: ubuntu-touch, proxy, ubuntu-emulator

I installed `ubuntu-emulator` with

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-emulator
```

Now, when I try to create an instance of the emulator I get this:

> Get https:// system-image.ubuntu.com / channels.json: Proxy Authentication Required

I'm behind a proxy with authentication.
I configured the proxy via GUI in System Settings -> Network
which does not allow to set an authentication and I tried:

```
export http_proxy=http://user:pwd@proxy.com:1234
export https_proxy=http://user:pwd@proxy.com:1234
```

with no luck

System updater, Firefox and apt work just fine.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it.
I had to login as root in the terminal with

```
sudo -s
```

then I had to set the proxy with:

```
export http_proxy=http:// user:password@proxyhost.com:1234
export https_proxy=http:// user:password@proxyhost.com:1234
export ftp_proxy=http:// user:password@proxyhost.com:1234
```

At this stage:

```
ubuntu-emulator create myInstance
```

worked

Hope this is helpful